# Android GSON: Parsing several different objects from the same response

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I'm working on porting an iPhone app that relies heavily on JSON to Android.
One of the responses that has to be parsed is used to build the main screen. The JSON response for this contains 3 different objects, namely Icons, Header and Player. These are all contained within the object Home.
Icons and Player both contain an Array of items, the Header is just a single item.

Now I'm still a beginner when it comes to JSON, and I'm not quite sure how I should parse this response. Therefore I would like to know if I have the right idea before working myself into problems.

My idea is to create 4 different classes, one for Home, icons, Header and Player. 
Home would contain an array of both Icons and Player, and an object of Header.
But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

The JSON response in questions is as followed: (Removed some objects due to the size of the response)

```
{
  "Home": {
    "Icon": [
      {
        "ScreenID": 533,
        "ScreenIndex": 1,
        "IconName": "mainIcon_news",
        "Title": "News",
        "FK_ModuleID": 6,
        "FormID": 567,
        "ModName": "News",
        "MediaType": "",
        "New_Icon": 0
      },
      {
        "ScreenID": 528,
        "ScreenIndex": 2,
        "IconName": "mainIcon_music",
        "Title": "Music",
        "FK_ModuleID": 3,
        "FormID": 562,
        "ModName": "Media",
        "MediaType": "Music",
        "New_Icon": 0
      }
    ],
    "Header": [
      {
        "ModHomeRotationID": 183,
        "image_url": "*****/Media/68/1216_5.jpg",
        "flg_RotationEnabled": false,
        "flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn": true,
        "flg_RotationRandomize": false,
        "flg_RotationDelayMS": 5000,
        "flg_RotationDelayFadeMS": 3000,
        "HomeRotationIndex": null
      }
    ],
    "Player": [
      {
        "MediaID": 1219,
        "Track_Name": "***",
        "song_url": "*****/Media/68/1219.mp3",
        "song_remote_url": null,
        "FileSize": 4700502
      },
      {
        "MediaID": 1220,
        "Track_Name": "**** ",
        "song_url": "*****/Media/68/1220.mp3",
        "song_remote_url": null,
        "FileSize": 4350222
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Could someone tell me if I'm in the right direction, and if not, what I should be doing instead? 
I should mention, I'm using GSON to parse the JSON responses at the moment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked my post? Do you have any queries?

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer yet, I was out for lunch. 
I've checked them yes, and I think that I'd be able to work it out from here. The second example is almost the same as my problem in means of the contents of the response, so I'm pretty sure I'll be able to sort out my problems using that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right you need to create Four classes and need to initialize  the values inside that class name..

Validate your Json using [**JSONLint**](http://jsonlint.com/) :

Then try this sample [Parsing JSON using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253815/gson-no-args-constructor-for-class-xyz-with-arrays)  and [One More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675714/phrasing-json-array-using-gson-for-google-search-api)