# Android GSON: Objects not being filled, but no errors occur

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

This question is a follow up to an earlier question of mine which can be found here: [Android GSON: Parsing several different objects from the same response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834894/android-gson-parsing-several-different-objects-from-the-same-response)

I followed the answer posted there, and created 4 seperate classes for my JSON response.
However, when parsing this response the objects get made (or so I think, since no parsing errors occur), but when trying to finding out the data of these objects NullPointers occur.

My JSON response is as following:

```
    {
  "Home": {
    "Icon": [
      {
        "ScreenID": 533,
        "ScreenIndex": 1,
        "IconName": "mainIcon_news",
        "Title": "News",
        "FK_ModuleID": 6,
        "FormID": 567,
        "ModName": "News",
        "MediaType": "",
        "New_Icon": 0
      },
      {
        "ScreenID": 528,
        "ScreenIndex": 2,
        "IconName": "mainIcon_music",
        "Title": "Music",
        "FK_ModuleID": 3,
        "FormID": 562,
        "ModName": "Media",
        "MediaType": "Music",
        "New_Icon": 0
      }
    ],
    "Header": [
      {
        "ModHomeRotationID": 183,
        "image_url": "*****/Media/68/1216_5.jpg",
        "flg_RotationEnabled": false,
        "flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn": true,
        "flg_RotationRandomize": false,
        "flg_RotationDelayMS": 5000,
        "flg_RotationDelayFadeMS": 3000,
        "HomeRotationIndex": null
      }
    ],
    "Player": [
      {
        "MediaID": 1219,
        "Track_Name": "***",
        "song_url": "*****/Media/68/1219.mp3",
        "song_remote_url": null,
        "FileSize": 4700502
      },
      {
        "MediaID": 1220,
        "Track_Name": "**** ",
        "song_url": "*****/Media/68/1220.mp3",
        "song_remote_url": null,
        "FileSize": 4350222
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My code to parse this response is as followed:

```
package com.mobowski.app.menusections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.mobowski.app.json.WebService;

import com.mobowski.app.listitems.Item;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

//import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestMain extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // setContentView(R.layout.mainlinks);
        retrieveLinks();

    }

    public void retrieveLinks() {
        // Instantiate the Web Service Class with he URL of the web service not
        // that you must pass

        WebService webService = new WebService(
                "http://editedduetosecurityreasons");

        // Pass the parameters
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("iAppID", "59");
        params.put("iUserID", "1");
        params.put("strCulName", "");
        // params.put("var", "");

        // Get JSON response from server the "" are where the method name would
        // normally go if needed example
        // webService.webGet("getMoreAllerts", params);
        String response = webService.webGet("", params);
        System.out.println("Returns: " + response);

        try {

            Home collection = new Gson().fromJson(response, Home.class);

            for (Icon icon : collection.icons) {
                System.out.println(icon.title);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Home {

        public List<Icon> icons;
        public Header header;
        public Player player[];

        public List<Icon> getIcons() {
            return icons;
        }

        public void setIcons(List<Icon> icons) {
            this.icons = icons;
        }

        public Header getHeader() {
            return header;
        }

        public void setHeader(Header header) {
            this.header = header;
        }

        public Player[] getPlayer() {
            return player;
        }

        public void setPlayer(Player[] player) {
            this.player = player;
        }

        public Player getSinglePlayer(int i) {
            return player[i];
        }

        public Icon getSingleIcon(int i) {
            return icons.get(i);
        }
    }

    public class Icon {

        public int ScreenID;
        public int ScreenIndex;
        public String IconName;
        public String title;
        public int FK_ModuleID;
        public int FormID;
        public String ModName;
        public String MediaType;
        public int New_Icon;

        public int getScreenID() {
            return ScreenID;
        }

        public void setScreenID(int screenID) {
            ScreenID = screenID;
        }

        public int getScreenIndex() {
            return ScreenIndex;
        }

        public void setScreenIndex(int screenIndex) {
            ScreenIndex = screenIndex;
        }

        public String getIconName() {
            return IconName;
        }

        public void setIconName(String iconName) {
            IconName = iconName;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public int getFK_ModuleID() {
            return FK_ModuleID;
        }

        public void setFK_ModuleID(int fK_ModuleID) {
            FK_ModuleID = fK_ModuleID;
        }

        public int getFormID() {
            return FormID;
        }

        public void setFormID(int formID) {
            FormID = formID;
        }

        public String getModName() {
            return ModName;
        }

        public void setModName(String modName) {
            ModName = modName;
        }

        public String getMediaType() {
            return MediaType;
        }

        public void setMediaType(String mediaType) {
            MediaType = mediaType;
        }

        public int getNew_Icon() {
            return New_Icon;
        }

        public void setNew_Icon(int new_Icon) {
            New_Icon = new_Icon;
        }

    }

    public class Player {

        public int MediaID;
        public String Track_Name;
        public String song_url;
        public String song_remote_url;
        public int FileSize;

        public int getMediaID() {
            return MediaID;
        }

        public void setMediaID(int mediaID) {
            MediaID = mediaID;
        }

        public String getTrack_Name() {
            return Track_Name;
        }

        public void setTrack_Name(String track_Name) {
            Track_Name = track_Name;
        }

        public String getSong_url() {
            return song_url;
        }

        public void setSong_url(String song_url) {
            this.song_url = song_url;
        }

        public String getSong_remote_url() {
            return song_remote_url;
        }

        public void setSong_remote_url(String song_remote_url) {
            this.song_remote_url = song_remote_url;
        }

        public int getFileSize() {
            return FileSize;
        }

        public void setFileSize(int fileSize) {
            FileSize = fileSize;
        }

    }

    public class Header {

        public int ModHomeRotationID;
        public String image_url;
        public boolean flg_RotationEnabled;
        public boolean flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn;
        public boolean flg_RotationRandomize;
        public int flg_RorationDelayMS;
        public int flg_RotationDelayFadeMS;
        public int HomeRotationIndex;

        public int getModHomeRotationID() {
            return ModHomeRotationID;
        }

        public void setModHomeRotationID(int modHomeRotationID) {
            ModHomeRotationID = modHomeRotationID;
        }

        public String getImage_url() {
            return image_url;
        }

        public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
            this.image_url = image_url;
        }

        public boolean isFlg_RotationEnabled() {
            return flg_RotationEnabled;
        }

        public void setFlg_RotationEnabled(boolean flg_RotationEnabled) {
            this.flg_RotationEnabled = flg_RotationEnabled;
        }

        public boolean isFlg_RotateOnlyOnReturn() {
            return flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn;
        }

        public void setFlg_RotateOnlyOnReturn(boolean flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn) {
            this.flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn = flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn;
        }

        public boolean isFlg_RotationRandomize() {
            return flg_RotationRandomize;
        }

        public void setFlg_RotationRandomize(boolean flg_RotationRandomize) {
            this.flg_RotationRandomize = flg_RotationRandomize;
        }

        public int getFlg_RorationDelayMS() {
            return flg_RorationDelayMS;
        }

        public void setFlg_RorationDelayMS(int flg_RorationDelayMS) {
            this.flg_RorationDelayMS = flg_RorationDelayMS;
        }

        public int getFlg_RotationDelayFadeMS() {
            return flg_RotationDelayFadeMS;
        }

        public void setFlg_RotationDelayFadeMS(int flg_RotationDelayFadeMS) {
            this.flg_RotationDelayFadeMS = flg_RotationDelayFadeMS;
        }

        public int getHomeRotationIndex() {
            return HomeRotationIndex;
        }

        public void setHomeRotationIndex(int homeRotationIndex) {
            HomeRotationIndex = homeRotationIndex;
        }

    }

}
```

However this code does not seem to work. A nullpointer occurs when `for (Icon icon : collection.icons) {` gets called. A NullPointer occurs when any method is used on any of the items that should have been made actually, with the exception of the Home object.

I'm sure this means I did something wrong, however I don't know what I did wrong or where. Could someone give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance for anyone who is willing to give it a try

---

After trying Venky's suggestion, it seems the data is parsing better now. However I'm still faced with a problem. While trying to parse the Header object, LogCat presents me the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: [{"ModHomeRotationID":162,"image_url":"***********/1020_5.jpg","flg_RotationEnabled":false,"flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn":true,"flg_RotationRandomize":false,"flg_RotationDelayMS":5000,"flg_RotationDelayFadeMS":3000,"HomeRotationIndex":null}]
```

I know this means it was expecting to receive an object, but got an array instead. However, my code is as such:

```
    public class Header {
        List<Header_info> header;
    }

    public class Header_info {
        public int ModHomeRotationID;
        public String image_url;
        public boolean flg_RotationEnabled;
        public boolean flg_RotateOnlyOnReturn;
        public boolean flg_RotationRandomize;
        public int flg_RorationDelayMS;
        public int flg_RotationDelayFadeMS;

    public int HomeRotationIndex;
}
```

I used the same method for the Icon objects, and those seem to parse fine (no errors).
Any suggestions why this won't work for the Header object? It seems to be of the same format as the Icons.

Comment: Not yet sorry, I'm currently back at school working on some other projects, I'll try your answer out when I get back home so I can work on my internship assignment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [GSON Response](http://pastie.org/private/ydvtvkbkoz4tfrnmvnyfg)

Validate the above response using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com)

Check the Output in Logcat : Since output printed using Log command:

Same type of output is Parsed , Make changes as per your needs.

Just check for **response and groups object**

Java Code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
RecordResponse cashResponse = null;
try {
cashResponse = gson.fromJson(response_data, RecordResponse.class);
} 
catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (JsonIOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
List<Result> results = cashResponse.response.groups;
for (Result cashResult : results){
for(Result_items rest : cashResult.items ){
    if(rest!=null && !rest.equals("")){
        Log.v("IDSSSSS", rest.name);
        Log.v("IDSSSSS", rest.id);
        Log.v("IDSSSSS", rest.location.distance);
        Log.v("IDSSSSS", rest.location.lat);
        Log.v("IDSSSSS", rest.location.lng);
        try{
            for(Result_category cat : rest.categories ){
                Log.v("category_icon", cat.id);
                Log.v("category_name", cat.icon);
                Log.v("category_id", cat.name);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}

    }
}
}
```

Correponding Class file for getting Data :

```
 class RecordResponse{
    CashGamesContainer response;
 }

  class CashGamesContainer{
     List<Result> groups;
  }

 class Result{
 List<Result_items> items;
 }
 class Result_items{
    String id;
String name;
String verified;
Locations location;
Stats  stats;
List<Result_category> categories;
  }

 class Locations{
String address;
String lat;
String lng;
String distance;
  }

  class Stats{
String checkinsCount;
String usersCount;
String tipCount;
   }

   class Result_category{
   String id;
   String name;
   String icon;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your example and I think it's parsing better now. However, I'm still faced with a problem.
I edited my problem in the first post

Comment: Fixed eventually, the fieldnames for the main object needed to be capitalized due to the response being capitalized as well. Thanks for getting me in the right direction though!